# Best tcl language compiler

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl language. Is there any compilers/IDE we can use which can suggest syntax errors while writing code
Any compilers or IDE that can perform syntax highlighting and also suggest errors while writing TCL scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl is not usually compiled (in the sense that you're suggesting). There are IDEs and code editors that support the language; for example, I know that Eclipse has Tcl support in the DLTK plugin, and Emacs has a Tcl mode that will pick up quite a few issues too. There are probably others, but I don't use those.

For more on the topic of syntax checkers, see this Stack Overflow question:
[Static detection of errors in Tcl scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163210/static-detection-of-errors-in-tcl-scripts). The answers are still valid.

Comment: SO is not just a perfect question-and-answer machine; it's _also_ a support channel. Yes, it's difficult to answer this sort of question without dragging things into the opinions… but it is possible. In particular, I'm careful to state that the list is not exhaustive and to not present an opinion as to which is best (that's a very individual thing IME). The other question is the best place to look (on SO) for Tcl syntax checkers. **I approve of closing this question** and contemplated closing as duplicate myself, but it wasn't quite…